# How to extract the data from the given filename?

Tags: import, string-manipulation, files-and-directories

Consider a few files with filename structure

```
data/Neutrino distribution functions/NAME_distribution_mass=XX.0_theta=0.YY.txt
```

where XX/YY may have an arbitrary number of digits.

I use

```
files= FileNames["*.txt", 
   FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
     "data/Neutrino distribution functions/"}]];
Filenames = 
 Table[Last@FileNameSplit@files[[i]], {i, 1, Length[files], 1}];
```

say,

```
 filenames = {"Electron_distribution_mass=100.0_theta=0.009238898.txt",
"Electron_distribution_mass=100.0_theta=0.01600224.txt",
"Electron_distribution_mass=10.0_theta=0.5074418.txt"}
```

Could you please tell me how to obtain the output in the form

```
{NAME,XX.0, 0.YY}
```

Edit.

It seems that I have solved this problem.

This is my current attempt:

```
 FilenameParameters[i_] :=  StringCases[filenames[[i]], 
 mixing__ ~~ "_distribution_mass=" ~~ mass : NumberString ~~ 
   "_theta=" ~~ angle : NumberString ~~ ".txt" :> {mixing, mass, 
   angle}]
```

E.g.,

```
FilenameParameters[1]
```

returns

{{"Electron", 100.0, 0.009238898}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using [`StringCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCases.html):

```
filename = "data/Neutrino distribution functions/NAME_distribution_mass=XX.0_theta=0.YY.txt";

First@StringCases[
   path__ ~~ "/" ~~ name__ ~~ "_distribution_mass=" ~~ mass__ ~~ "_theta=" ~~ theta__ ~~ ".txt" :>
    {name, mass, theta}
   ]@filename
(* {"NAME", "XX.0", "0.YY"} *)
```